# How to create a loader component in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

Create a loader component and call it from all other  component across the project. Where I can pass the loader status and custom message every time I call the loader from different component. Hopefully a function with 2 arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I konw two ways :

1. Inject the `Loader` component into the `Header` or `Footer` or into the Parent Component and you can call it with [ref][1]
2. Inject the `Loader` component into the `Header` or `Footer` or into the Parent Component and you can use a shared state lib like `redux`to call it

Answer (score 0):

https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-fast-h5ugs?file=/src/Preloader.js

Something like this:

Parent Component

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'

import Preloader from './Preloader'
import OtherComponent from './OtherComponent'

const App = () => {
  //create loader message in state
  const [loader, setLoader] = useState("")

  //create message setter
  const messageSetter = (message) => {
    setLoader(message);
  }

  //render pre loader on whether loader message exists
  //pass messege setter to other components
  return (
    <div>
        {loader && <Preloader message={loader}/>}
        <OtherComponent messageSetter={messageSetter} />
    </div>
  )
 
}

 export default App;
```

Child Component

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';


const OtherComponent = ({messageSetter}) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState("");

    //mock api call
    const yourFunction = async () => {
        let mockApi =  new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            setTimeout(()=> {
                resolve("Your data.");
            },2000)
        });
        //await data
        let result = await mockApi;
        //set data to state
        setData(result);
        //close loader
        messageSetter('');
    }

    //call loader with custom message and api call on click 
    return(
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => {messageSetter("custom loading message"); yourFunction();}}>Click</button>
            <div>{data? data : "No data called."}</div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default OtherComponent;
```

Loader Component

```
import React from 'react';

//if needed give it absolute position via css and raise z index
const Preloader = ({message}) => {
    return(
        <div>{message}</div>
    )
}

export default Preloader;
```